# Cannot import module after update to Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm having an issue with importing my shared module written in Angular to another Angular app. With v2.4.9 everything works fine but after update to v4.0.x I get an error with RxJS.

```
ERROR in ...../app/node_modules/app-common/src/app/shared/services/api.service.ts (30,14): Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
...../app/node_modules/app-common/src/app/shared/services/api.service.ts (39,14): Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.
...../app/node_modules/app-common/src/app/shared/services/api.service.ts (49,14): Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.
...../app/node_modules/app-common/src/app/shared/services/api.service.ts (58,14): Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.
```

Here's the thing:
I have two directories - /app-common and /app - I am importing the shared module via 'npm link' so I can reach it in /app/node_modules/app-common/ directory. I was having some issues with it before and I also had to place "paths" section in tsconfig.json file to point all angular and rxjs modules. I also tried to make a new project using stable angular-cli v1.0.0 and @angular@4.0.0 but I get the same error. The strange thing also is when sometimes I change some file by just adding a space character and save, webpack is recompiling the source and sometimes it works but only after change, not after running it for the first time. So as you can guess - 'ng build' command is also giving me the same error.

PS. yes - I have imported operators from rxjs and also when I am trying to import all of them via:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

nothing changes - still error.

Any ideas?